# No menu buttons in Kdenlive (Ubuntu 18.04 - Gnome)

Tags: gnome, menu, kdenlive

Weirdly the menu buttons disappeared. [image]

[image]

Kdenlive 18.04.2 flatpak or Kdenlive 18.04.1 appimage. Both experience the same issue with the menu. Not the old Kdenlive 4:17.12.3-0ubuntu1 though. What could it be?

I have to mention that I reinstalled them multiple times without any luck - also deleted the config files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you delete ALL Kdenlive files (search Home folder for them). Uninstall Kdenlvie, then delete all files, then everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Did you changed your theme? Basic buttons are referred to the icon theme you use. If so change to the default one test if this is the reason.

Comment: Nope that didn't work. Could be something weird with multiple installations of flatpaks versions snaps or canonical. But as I provided the answer you can delete the kdenlive files and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

I'm searching about this issue, 
and found [this post](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=269&t=142775#p383686) solving my problem

I think KDEnlive is still using the KDE shortcut environment.

So <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> absolutely solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings - Configure Toolbars

in Avaliable actions: type Render

Choose it and klik right arrow button